# How do you solve a system of linear equations in modulus arithmetic?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Say you have a system if equations of the form:

$ax+by \equiv z \mod(n)$

$cx + dy \equiv w \mod(n)$

Where the only unkown values are x and y

What is the approach to solve a system like this?

Comment: I don't know what to try

I know how to solve it without the modular arithmetic part by using linear combinations. Is it the same here?

Comment: When $n$ is prime, this can be done by matrix methods, as we have a field

Comment: Just solve it as you would for "normal" simulataneous equations ... multiply the first equation by $d$ & the second by $b$, and then subtract ... if $ad-bc$ and $n$ have a common factor then there might be a problem, indicating no solution.

Comment: " I know how to solve it without the modular arithmetic part by using linear combinations. Is it the same here?"  Well, every answer you get in "regular" arithmatic will have to be an answer in modulo arithmatic because if $A = B$ then $A \equiv B \mod n$.  But there may be multiple solutions.  Try solving $ax + by = nj + z$ and $cx + dy = nm + w$ and see what you get.

Comment: @fleablood yes I know I am gonna get infinite answers, but my query is whether I am guaranteed that all answers cna be described as: answer to the linear system+nk

Comment: If you solve for $nm + w$ and $nj + z$ take a note what happens to the $n$ in that.  You might get a fraction of the $n$ and you can adjust your answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

For a 2 by 2,
just use Cramer's rule:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cramer%27s_rule

Comment: can you show this works in modular arithmetic as well?

Comment: Everything that can be done in "regular" arithmetic can be done in modular arithmetic.

Comment: That's not fully true, in normal arithemtic $a^2=b^2  \implies a=b$ or $a=-b$ but in modular arithmetic that's not necessarily the case. e.g $2^2\equiv 4^4 \pmod 4$ however $2 \not\equiv 4 \text{ nor } -4 \pmod 4$

Comment: Depends what the modulus is. If it’s prime, you’re good to go.

Answer (score 0):

If you solve it *regularly* you get $y = \frac {aw - cz}{da-cb}$ and $x = \frac {zd - bw}{da-cb}$.

The only issue is if $\frac 1{da-cb}$ will be expressible modulo $n$.

Reduce these fractions to lowest terms:  Let's say $x = \frac {zd-bw}{da-cb} = \frac AB$.

Then we need to solve $Bx \equiv A \mod n$.  That will have a solution if and only if $\gcd(B,n) = 1$.  If $\gcd(B, n) > 1$ then for $B\equiv A \mod n$ (i.e. if $A = mn + B$ then $\gcd(n,B)|A$ which is a contradiction to them being in lowest terms.

And if $\gcd(B, n) =1$ then you can solve $jB + kn = 1$.  So solve for $j*B \equiv 1 \mod n$.  We can call that $\frac 1B \equiv j \mod n$.

This does *not* mean that $j = kn + \frac 1B$ for some integer $n$ but is *does* mean that $jB \equiv 1 \mod n$.

Thus $x \equiv \frac AB \equiv jA \mod n$ will be the solution.

....

It may be easier to see this with an example $2x + 3y = 3$ and $2x - 3y = -1$ mean that $x = \frac 12$ and $y = \frac 23$.

We want to solve $2x + 3y \equiv 3 \mod 5$ and $2x - 3y \equiv -1 \equiv 4 \mod 5$.

So we must find value for $\frac 12 \mod 5$.  i.e a solution to $2x \equiv 1 \mod 5$.  That is ... $3$.  So $x \equiv 3 \mod 5$.

And we must find a value for $\frac 13 \mod 5$.i.e. a solution to $3x\equiv 1 \mod 5$.  Well that is $2$.  So $y \equiv \frac 23 \equiv 2*2 \equvi 4 \mod 5$

And does that work?  $2*3 + 3*4 \equiv 18\equiv 3 \mod 5$.  And $2*3 - 3*4 \equiv -6 \equiv 4 \mod 5$.

Yup, it works.

===

An example that wouldn't work is $2x + 3y \equiv 3 \mod 6$ and $2x - 3y \equiv -1 \equiv 5 \mod 6$.

We'd need to solve $\frac 12 \equiv \mod 6$ i.e. a solution to $2x \equiv 1 \mod 6$ and there is no such answer.  Likewise there is no solution to $3x \equiv 1 \mod 6$.  So there is no solution.

Which makes sense.

Conside $2x + 3y \equiv 3 \mod 6$.  If $y$ is odd then $x$ must be a multiple of $3$.  If $y$ is even then $2x \equiv 3\mod 6$.  That's impossible. $2x - 3$ must be a multiple of $6$ so $x$ must be a multiple of $3$ but that makes $2x\equiv 0 \mod 6$.

So the only solution is $y$ is odd and $x$ is a multiple of $3$.

But $2x -3y = 2(3k) - 3(2j + 1) \equiv 3\mod 6 \not \equiv -1 \mod 6$.